# Is a new DNA sample required for paternal haplotype or maternal mitochondria analysis

Tags: y-dna, mitochondrial-dna

A year ago I sent in a DNA sample to Ancestry for autosomal analysis. I have the RAW DNA data file. Can that data be used with 23&me or another testing company to have mitochondria and  paternal hapalog analyzed or, is another sample needed?

Comment: Welcome to the Genealogy & Family History SE. Be sure to take the [tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Comment: Comment rather than answer because I haven't gone looking for anything to back up my belief, but given that Ancestry doesn't do haplotypes, and mitochondrial DNA is from a different part of your cells than autosomal DNA, I would say that no, your raw data from Ancestry cannot be used to determine your Y/mt groupings. (And in any case, 23andMe doesn't accept any sort of uploads.)

Answer (score 1):

I have sent your qestion to the 23andMe helpdesk and they said that they don't offer this service.

> It is not possible to import genetic data from other services into a 23andMe account. Therefore you will need to purchase a kit directly from our website.

They do go on to say that

> We understand that other services support this functionality

Of course they don't say which services, but if you google around for other testing companies and ask their helpdesk, you might find one that does.

Comment: Worth adding that FamilyTreeDNA do the most comprehensive mtDNA and YDNA testing, but they need a fresh sample as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can that data be used with 23&me or another testing company to have mitochondria and paternal hapalog analyzed or, is another sample needed?

What do you want to do? Please describe more precisely.

Unfortunately, different companies use different chips and different methodics for obtaining and interpreting DNA data, so **there is a way to import**, for example, 23andMe (or Ancestry) data into FTDNA Lab, but **it is limited in features** and will give you only basic information. It is also the commercial question, because FTDNA (and any other lab) wants everybody to buy it's own tests.
Another idea is that there is big probability that 23andMe (or Ancestry) raw data contains Y-DNA and mtDNA data. You may extract this data on your own from your raw DNA file, but as 23andMe (or Ancestry) test is less comprehensive than FT-DNA's Y-DNA and mtDNA tests, the results will be less precise.

For example, you may use this tool: https://ytree.morleydna.com/extractFromAutosomal to extract Y-DNA info from 23andMe/Ancestry data.